# How do I get vectors out of nominal data from a database table for use in cosine similarity?

Tags: cluster-analysis, cosine-similarity

Take the following fictitious dataset.

```
id, gender, race, city, county, major.
1, Male, White, St. Paul, Ramsey, computer science
2, Female, White, St. Paul, Ramsey, math
3, Male, Black, Bismark, Gotham, English
4, Female, Asian, New York, Betty, computer science.
```

I want to calculate the similarity between each record and research has shown that perhaps cosine similarity may render good results. My stumbling block is how to build the vectors for each record. That is if I am comparing record 1 and record 2, I need to convert record 1 into v1 and r2 into v2 then apply cosine similarity. How can this be done?

If perhaps there is another and better solution in comparing these records i would love to learn about it.

Comment: Obviously the result will be very similar to Hamming distance, which is much easier to explain here. Cosine is more appropriate for actual text, but your data is tabular. But generally I strongly suggest that you don't choose the tools you want to use, but first formalize the *problem* that you want to solve. Begin with the math first.

Comment: Generally I doubt that you can get meaningful results on this data that are better than trivial "group by" results, because of the data. Exactly because of this problem you need to first properly define your objective: what is a good result? (Equation?)

Comment: Unfortunately the "tools" were decided before I even saw the data. I suppose I could try and find "alternate" data but that could take time. The overall idea is using Affinity Propagation, and I didn't know that the data I would receive would be so nominal. I was hoping it would be numeric. The problem I am solving is to "categorize" student enrollment for high school or university enrollment to describe "exemplar" students that the describe the whole of the dataset and target their characteristics.

Comment: For that purpose kmodes would be the obvious choice on such data, but I doubt that it will give particularly good results because of the data. Here a mode may be multiple students with the same data.

Comment: Followup. In checking out KModes, I found this link https://shapeofdata.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/cast-study-2-tokens-in-census-data/ which presents a python application that takes nominal data and can reduce the dimensionality of it down to 2. I can see the plots of the data. I'm thinking through these 2-D plots I can get eucludian distance. Would you agree with that argument?

Comment: No, PCA usually does not produce convincing results. You can try, obviously. But how do you get back your representatives?

Comment: stratch my previous comments. I actually have a working AP, or it seems to work that uses the algorithms proposed in these two papers: https://edu.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/EC/lehre/sommersemester-2013/wissenschaftliches-schreiben-in-der-informatik/publikationen-fuer-studentische-vortraege/kMeansMixedCatNum.pdf and https://edu.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/EC/lehre/sommersemester-2013/wissenschaftliches-schreiben-in-der-informatik/publikationen-fuer-studentische-vortraege/kMeansMixedCatNum.pdf. I haven't looked at error analysis yet. That might be prove difficult.